# how to regenerate different session for two different guards in laravel after login?

Tags: laravel

**I m trying to implement multi authentication and i have two guards :one is web(default) and another is admin and for both case in logincontroller i have regenerate session this way:**

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

**login of admin**:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('profile');
        }
```

**logout of admin:**

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {   
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

**Now the problem is whenever i logout from admin side i automatically get logout from user side too if i was logged in previously.so this is what i don't want.anyone help me to solve this issue?
thank you!!**

Comment: try   $request->user('admin')->session()->regenerate();

Comment: and what about while invalidate ? on doing $request->session()->invalidate(); it will flushed out all available session_id

Comment: try using request->user('admin')->session()->invalidate();

Comment: let me know if it works or not

Comment: threw this error ```Call to undefined method App\Models\Admin::session()```

Comment: okay.then its not the option. if possible  i will try to reflicate your scenario.